# How can I parse a dataframe which has only date and month columns to new column with pd.datetime format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, data-science

[A small snippet from my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwGdt.png)

I have separate columns for month and date. I need to parse only month and date into a pandas datetime type(other datetime types would also help), so that I could plot a TimeSeries Line plot.

I tried this piece of code,

```
df['newdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Days','Month']], format='%d%m')
```

but I threw me an error

```
KeyError: "['Days' 'Month'] not in index"
```

How should I approach this error?

Comment: of what dtype are your Month and days columns? as dtype string, you should be able to use `pd.to_datetime(df['Month']+df['Days'], format='%d%m')`

Comment: tl@MrFuppes Both the columns are int64, and they seem to work fine. But however, the problem comes when I look closely at the result. Dates from 11-Jan to 19-Jan and 21-Jan to 30-Jan are displaced to the November month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an illustration of my comment; if you take the columns as type string, you can join and strptime them easily as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month': [1,2,11,12], 'Days': [1,22,3,23]})

pd.to_datetime(df['Month'].astype(str)+' '+df['Days'].astype(str), format='%m %d')
# 0   1900-01-01
# 1   1900-02-22
# 2   1900-11-03
# 3   1900-12-23
# dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You could also add a 'Year' column to your df with an arbitrary year number and use the method you originally intended:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month': [1,2,11,12], 'Days': [1,22,3,23]})
df['Year'] = 2020
pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Days']])
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work fine for months:Feb(2) to Dec(12), but for January(1) it SKIPS dates from 11 to 19 and 21 to 30.

Comment: @vaidhyanathanchandramouli: this is an excellent point, I haven't thought of this! It should work if you join the columns by e.g. a space and add that also to the strptime format. I've also added another option how you could do this without conversion to string, see my edit.

Comment: Yes. I added a separator and I got what I wanted. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: @vaidhyanathanchandramouli: great. if performance is an issue, have a look at the second option using a dummy year column - should be a bit more efficient than strptime.

Comment: I did use a 'year' value at the end. It added a bit more nuance to my plot.